# extract integer by digit position Swift

Tags: swift3, uipickerview

I have several pickerViews throughout the app where users input data.  Later, I will display this data as a "summary" page.  Displaying the data is clearly easy.  However, if the user wants to "edit" the data, I want the same digits to load in the pickerView.
There will be case of 4 digits, 3 digits, 2 digits and a single digit.
So, I need to have the ability to determine which digit is in which position, if there is a digit.

So, if the integer is 321, how to get "1" as the first digit, "2" as the second digit and "3" as the third digit.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myPicker.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

You replace your row and 0 with your values. Then to get the numbers, only thing on my mind now would be something like

```
while number > 0 {
    let digit = number%10 // do what you want with the digit
    number = round(number/10)
}
```